# Adonis 5 pagination ignoring data created from queries in hooks

Tags: typescript, adonis.js

Im trying to create soft delete functionality using hooks... similar to how the example is in the [documentation](https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/models/hooks). This works fine.

My issue is the pagination used in the controller does not detect any of the query changes used in the `@beforeFetch()` hook and returns the total records (deleted and active). So the pagination meta data stays the same, even though the hook has been added and the data is different. I did notice the `@beforePaginate()` hook exists, but it doesnt work as expected and there is no documentation about this.

How can I update the pagination?

**Product Model:**

```
 @beforeFetch()
  public static softDeletesFetch = (query: ModelQueryBuilderContract<typeof Product>) => {
    query.whereNull('deleted_at')
  }
```

**Product Controller:**

```
  public async index({ request }) {

    const publicProductColumns = [
      'id',
      'categoryId',
      'name',
      'summary',
      'productCode',
      'manufacturer',
      'price'
    ]

    const currentPage = request.input('current_page', 1)
    const perPage = request.input('per_page', 20)
    const products = Product.query()

    products
      .select(publicProductColumns)
      //other stuff omited for clarity
 
    return await products.paginate(currentPage, perPage)
  }
```

**Output:**

```
 "meta": {
        "total": 369, //<---This stays same
        "per_page": 20,
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 19,
        "first_page": 1,
        "first_page_url": "/?page=1",
        "last_page_url": "/?page=19",
        "next_page_url": "/?page=2",
        "previous_page_url": null
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found was to use Scopes insted of hooks, for example

```
@beforeFetch()
      public static softDeletesFetch = (query: ModelQueryBuilderContract<typeof Product>) => {
        query.whereNull('deleted_at')
      }
```

would become

```
public static softDelete = scope((query) => {
    query.whereNull('deleted_at')
  });
```

and used like this

```
    const products = Product.query().withScopes(scope => scope.softDelete())
```